# Web HTML Game not working on Samsung TV HG32EE590

Tags: html, samsung-smart-tv, construct-2

This game HTML5 link is not working on this Samsung TV HG32EE590.

It takes a very long time to load - then just shows a black screen.

The game is built in Construct 2 (I am aware not great!)

But I have exported the game into HTML5.

If anyone has any experience with this and can help please contact me.

Answer (score 0):

You provided too few data for an answer, there can be a lot of reasons. How about you post some code and give a bit more detail on the process of getting to an export file and how you run it on the TV? Have you tried running the HTML export on your computer?

Is your TV capable of running .exe files or install from .apk? If so, you can export it in those formats.

Does your TV support HTML5 canvas? It could be simple as that, but unless you provide more info there is no real way of helping you.